# Python break for loop

Tags: python

I am new to `Python`, but I think reserved words must have similar meaning in programming. However, I don't know why the `break` inside the 2nd `if-condition` breaks two `for-loop`.

I want to check if the list is empty or not, so I use a `while-loop`. It is supposed that if `newList` still has elements, it will stay in the `loop2`. However, after the `break` in `con2`, it goes directly to `loop1` even `newList` still has element.

```
while list:
    print ("loop1")
    result = 'n'
    for e in list:
        print ("loop2")
        result = 'n'
        for h in longList:
            print ("loop3")
            for i in e.getList():
                print ("loop4")
                if (i == h.getId()):
                    print ("con1")
                    result = 'y'
                    break
            if (result == 'y'):
                print ("con2")
                break
```

Comment: Simplify your code please. Please read [“How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A break statement will only break from one loop. Can you provide the 'newList' data structure contents?

Comment: I have simplified it

Comment: I know exactly, but why it goes directly to `loop1` instead of staying in the `for-loop` (`loop2`)?

Answer (score 1):

Your `break` statement is breaking from both loops because if you look just before you execute the first `break` statement, you assign the value `y` to the variable `result`. After you `break` from your first loop, the next line that gets tested is `if (result == 'y'):` and then you `break` again

```
while newList:
    print ("loop1")
    result = 'n'
    for node in newList:
        print ("loop2")
        result = 'n'
        for parent in parents:
            print ("loop3")
            for neighbourId in node.getNeighbours():
                print ("loop4")
                if (neighbourId == parent.getId()):
                    print ("con1")
                    result = 'y' # assignment
                    break # first break
            if (result == 'y'): # occurs after the first break and will be true
                print ("con2")
                break # second break
    else:
         print('This loop was not terminated with a break statement')
else:
   print('while loop ended')
```

Update:
In Python you can add an `else` clause to a loop and this `else` clause will only run if the loop has executed in full i.e never reached a `break` statement

Comment: Yep, it breaks the `parent` loop, so it should go to `loop2`, but it goes to `loop1`, which means it breaks the `for node in newList:` loop

Comment: How many values are in 'newList'? Are you sure the breaking doesnt occur on the last iteration?

Comment: Of course I do, as I did even print the `newList` inside `con2`

Comment: My `newList` has 2 elements, and it prints the statement you added twice

Comment: That's probably because your outer loop 'while newList' is running twice. This code is loopinception. The else clause on a loop will only run once, when the loop terminates

Comment: You must be seeing the message 'loop1' twice as well?

Comment: yep, it is supposed to be in `loop2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154980/discussion-between-ak47-and-androidnewbie).